# How Do I Import a 3D Object into Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, object, import, model, 3d

I wanted to know if anyone here knows how to import a 3D Object (i.e. Maya 3D Model) into Adobe Flex Application? I needed to create a simple Flex application which will allow me to rotate the 3D Object by dragging but I cannot seem to start doing it because I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I can import my 3D model into Flex.

This is exactly what I wanted to do: [3D Object in Flex](http://flexarena.blogspot.com/2006/10/3d-wireframe-renderer-for-flex.html)

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey @Kim So do you already have it in ase format ?

Comment: hello there again. i think my friend already knows how to do this and i'm not quite sure if he used ase format for the 3d. i'll just post the solution here when i see him :D  but thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to do this:

1. Using a [Flash Player 10 Collada Parser](https://web.archive.org/web/20160517104003/http://www.neuroproductions.be:80/experiments/flashplayer-10-collada-parser/):

[image: flash player 10 collada parser]
<sub>(source: [neuroproductions.be](http://www.neuroproductions.be/uploads/blog/examples/collada/collada_flash.jpg))</sub>

2. Using [Flex+Papervision3D](https://www.afternic.com/forsale/dehash.com?utm_source=TDFS_DASLNC&utm_medium=DASLNC&utm_campaign=TDFS_DASLNC&traffic_type=TDFS_DASLNC&traffic_id=daslnc&page_id=226) and an exported 3d model
3. Using [Flex+Away3D](http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/using_away3d_with_flex/) and an exported 3d model

You can export Collada from Maya and most 3d packages out there(3dsmax, cinema4d, blender, etc.). Aside from Kris Temmerman's Collada Parser, both Papervision3D and Away3D have importers for Collada + many other formats(obj, 3ds, kmz, etc.)

Make your choice if you want to use an as3 library or not, then load your model.
Once the model is loaded, you can can control the rotation and write your [arcball](http://unitzeroone.com/blog/2009/09/08/source-better-flash-10-3d-interaction-arcball/) implementation.

HTH,
George

Comment: yes, thank you. apparently my friend used PaperVision3D for it. thanks for the answers :D